# Software requires CPU with AVX instruction set enabled

Tags: windows-10, installation, cpu, compatibility, intel-core-i7

The software doesn't want to install it says (see the picture below).

I have a powerful machine (Core i7, 8GB RAM SSD etc).

However it's and old one though so probably those new instruction sets are not supported.

What are my options? Is there any way to kind of emulate those IS?

Additional info: [image: CPU info]

[image: Software refuses to install]

Comment: Your CPU doesn't support it. Sadly it's that simple. So it's either new hardware or new software. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Dave, the question is clear: Is there any way to kind of emulate those IS?

Comment: Like this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator

Comment: Have you checked if the instruction set can be enabled disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, but not, the motherboard doesn't know that IS exists. since it's old. The main question is rather is it possible to emulate it's existance but looks like it's not possible

Comment: The link that Dave gave you looks like it would do the trick, but it looks like it essentially wraps itself around your program to trap and emulate the required instructions. I'd expect that to be quite slow though. You cannot simply emulate new CPU functions system wide without some very low level kernel work. It could be possible, but considering the amount of time to do it would probably be several man years I suspect most companies just invest in newer hardware instead or simply use software that does not have such requirements.

Comment: Your CPU doesn't really support AVX at all since it's based on Intel's Nehalem architecture (2008-2010), but AVX only came a year later in 2011 with Sandy Bridge Core Ix CPUs.
Apart from the "Intel Software Development Emulator", there's no way to use AVX with your CPU at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running it in the [Intel Software Development Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator), which can catch and dynamically translate attempts to perform AVX instructions (among many other extensions to the X86 architecture).

It may *not* work; if it does, it'll be slower and perhaps more unreliable than it should be. But it's worth a shot. Note that if the software checks CPUID, it may be necessary to use specific emulator flags.

It's unlikely to work if the software installs a driver because these are not part of the emulated process.